# My UDF is extremely slow, explain not working

Tags: user-defined-functions, ibm-midrange

I've recently started working on IBM I AS/400.
I'm trying to make a function that selects different things dependant on 4 inputs, some times it'll make a chain operation, which should be close to free... **but** it ain't.

Function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION yxdb.GET_SEARCH_RESULT_TYPE (stakeholder_id INTEGER, account_number INTEGER, search_type VARCHAR(10),search_type_ref INTEGER)
RETURNS varchar(40)
LANGUAGE SQL
DETERMINISTIC --caching as parameter ==> svar. || 'not deterministic' ==> no caching.
NOT FENCED
BEGIN
DECLARE name VARCHAR(40);
    SET name = CASE WHEN search_type = 'EMNADRESSE' THEN 
        --email 
        'Email 1'
     WHEN search_type = 'FFADRESSE ' THEN 
        -- Hovedadresse                  
       -- 'Hovedadresse'
        CASE WHEN account_number = 0
        THEN 'Interessent'
        ELSE 'Konto'
        END
     WHEN search_type = 'TNKLEVADR ' THEN
        --Tankleveringsadresse
        --'Tankleveringsadresse'
        'Tank ' ||  (select TKVOL ||' - ' ||  TKBRUG from tkmstp where tknr = search_type_ref and tkknnr = account_number)
     ELSE 
        search_type
    END;
    RETURN name;
END;
```

So effective time will be around 9 seconds, when using this for 167 rows, but explain plan says it should only take ~171 ms each. (I know this is under optimal performance).

Tried to comment out `||  (select TKVOL ||' - ' ||  TKBRUG from tkmstp where tknr = search_type_ref and tkknnr = account_number)` Then it performs extremely fast.

Tried to toggle `fenced`, tried to toggle `Deterministic`.

I've tried to create it as a subselect, in the main query, this is also very fast...

The Usage:

```
select stake.*, yxdb.GET_SEARCH_RESULT_TYPE(1,fkkntnr, fkreltyp, FKPRDREF) RESULT_TYPE from frnkonp stake
where stake.fkkonidn in (202818,203116,941284,941285)
```

Is UDF not performing when containing selects?

Comment: You're probably more experienced than I, and I am merely interested in seeing what someone responds, but maybe my amateur questions will get you thinking!  Is the table tkmstp cached anywhere? or each time your UDF is called doesn't it have to go search it again? (Or what/how would optimize this?) and if so, does it use an indexed view on the keys you are providing?

Comment: SQL isn't RPG....and a single row select isn't as fast as a CHAIN.

Comment: @Charles Yes I know. Still should be quite close? I used to do this kind of thing in oracle, was very fast, and increased the readability/flexibility of the applications running the querys immensely.

Comment: @CodyG. It's not cached besides the deterministic way. I agree that it should not be as simple as a chain operation, but it should be 10seconds for 170ish rows.